# Apache JMeter test Dynamic URL

Tags: php, testing, jmeter

How can I test this page of my site with this dynamic URL using JMeter?

URL:

```
http://********************/index.php?theme=%7BC9F11D78-448E-4EAC-A766-C904ED98458E%7D&eventName=IncidentsItem&PHPSESSID=fb32581st66uvg1vnrpaj66fl5&internalurltime=1511811034521
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP Request you should use `Server Name or IP` which is the URL,

You can use it as a property that will be sent in command line or in user/jmeter.properties and get it with [property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function as `${__property(url)}`

You can enter variable/other function inside the field see [using user variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#user_variables)

For variable set using User Parameters and use it in field as `${url}`

For function you can use as function as [CSVRead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) as `${__CSVRead(urls.txt,0)}` for read urls from file.